# SQL Server : detect column changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to detect any changes in a column. Let me describe my problem exactly.

Let's say I have 400 stored procedures and 20 of them changes a column named `ModDate` in a table `Users`. But the `ModDate` column is not enough for me to achieve my goal. I need a dirty bit column let's say `IsChanged`.

My solution would be find and check the procedures that updates `Users.ModDate` and change these procedures to update `IsChanged` as well. But this is not efficient in time. Also, I may miss some procedures and this will cause problems.

So, my question; is it possible to alter a table/column to create an "on change" trigger? When any procedure changes the value of `Users.ModDate`, SQL Server will update the `IsChanged` column as 1 automatically.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Yes, use a trigger!

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You can take a look at SQL Server change tracking mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a trigger on a column for different crud events.

See https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-create-trigger/

```
`CREATE TRIGGER [schema_name.]trigger_name ON table_name AFTER {[INSERT],[UPDATE],[DELETE]} [NOT FOR REPLICATION] AS {sql_statements`}
```